# Twig: Pass Twig Markup to an Include

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I want to pass a macro(icon()) to a nested template of mine, through passing the markup as text.
But due to the |raw filter, Twig wont render the markup as Twig. Is there a way to achieve this? Basically I get this rendered `{{ icon("phone-call") }}`

**main.html.twig**

```
{% embed "Block/context_box_column_lane.html.twig" with {
    'title': 'Test',
    'subtitle': 'Subtitle',
    'text': '
        <p class="context-box-text">{{ icon("phone-call") }}</p>
    '
} %}{% endembed %}
```

**context_box_column_lane.html.twig**

```
{% extends "Block/section_sidebar.html.twig" %}

{% block section_content %}
    {% embed 'Block/context-box.html.twig' %}{% endembed %}
{% endblock %}
```

**context-box.html.twig**

```
{% from "@html/macros/icons.twig" import get as icon %}

<div class="b-context-box {% if has_border %}has-border{% endif %}">
    {% if subtitle %}
        <h3 class="section-subtitle">{{ subtitle|trans }}</h3>
    {% endif %}

    {% block content %}
        {% if text is defined %}
            {{ text|trans|raw }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you go with: `'text': '<p class="foo">'~icon("phone_call")~'</p>',`

Comment: @DarkBee This works, thank you very much!!! I imported my macro (icon) in **main.html.twig**. I am not sure if this is the optimal to do this though. I will do it like this for now.